# Disable Button for a short time to avoid double click

Tags: java, android

i am using following code to take a picture

```
 captureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });
```

The problem is sometimes if user just presses the button twice instantly, it crashes with following error

j

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1202)
at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1147)
at com.diadori.thevow.CameraActivity$4.onClick(CameraActivity.
```

How can i prevent user from double clicking instantly on a Button in android?

Comment: what about disabling the button after you clicked? and before the `onClick()` method finished you enable the button again.

Comment: It seems that `takePicture` is async. You'll need to disable it on click and re-enable it in the callback.

Comment: @Leviathan How am i suppose to do this can u give me example? i mean  disable and then calling this function and then disable 3 lines of code will work?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, the general pattern for button debouncing is to use a state variable, such as `if( !mClicking ) { mClicking = true; mCamera.takePicture... }` and don't forget to reset the variable in one of the call-backs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the button in `onClick()` and then again set your `clickListener` somewhere when your picture has been saved or whatever you intent to do with it.

Comment: ah i see mPicture is itself a listener

Comment: Got it, i placed the enable on mPicture listener :)

Answer (score -1):

I thought about this.

```
 captureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    captureBtn.setEnabled(false);
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    captureBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
```

Comment: This won't help as in `onClick()` the button will get disabled and enable immedeately, so it's not very safe doing that.